# How to create channel interceptor programmatically in spring

Tags: spring, spring-integration, mqtt

I want to create programmatically the following XML config on demand:

```
<int-mqtt:message-driven-channel-adapter id="inboundAdapter"
        client-id="${mqtt.client.id}"
        url="${mqtt.broker.url}"
        topics="${mqtt.subscribed.topics}"
        client-factory="clientFactory"
        channel="input-channel-1" converter="customConverter" />

    <int:channel id="input-channel-1">
        <int:queue/>
        <int:interceptors>
            <int:wire-tap channel="logger"/>
            <int:ref bean="messageListener"/>
        </int:interceptors>
    </int:channel>

    <int:channel id="logger" />

    <int:logging-channel-adapter channel="logger"
    auto-startup="true" level="INFO" id="loggerAdapter" log-full-message="true" />
```

What i can do is the following

```
CustomMqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter = new CustomMqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter(url, clientId, topic);
adapter.setOutputChannel(outputChannel);
adapter.setConverter(ctx.getBean("customConverter", MyPahoMessageConverter.class));
```

Now I need to add interceptor bean through which each client will get notified when message arrives according to their subscribed topics respectively.

### What I am trying to achieve is:

1) Create mqtt adapter when a client connects to server.(each client will subscribe to different topics as per configuration)

2) Dispose mqtt adapter when client disconnects.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you are trying to do; what do you have downstream of the `input-channel-1` in the XML configuration.

What does `messageListener` do?

It is an anti-pattern to put business logic in a channel; unless it's something really lightweight, consider invoking it using a `<service-activator/>` instead - possibly by making `input-channel-1` a pub-sub channel.

To answer your simple question, to add the interceptor, you can use `outputChannel.addInterceptor(ctx.getBean("messageListener", ChannelInterceptor.class));`.

Comment: messageListener is a bean class which extends ChannelInterceptorAdapter and overrides its preSend(message,channel) method. The logic inside the interceptor method is heavy-weight so I should not prefer this approach of adding channel-interceptors. I'll take a look into <service-activator /> from [spring-doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/overview.html#overview-endpoints-service-activator). Nice catch!. BTW can I create service activator on the fly ?

Comment: I don't have any downstream configuration for input-channel-1. when messages keep arriving, the queue will reach to its capacity(?) and cause abnormal condition ?

Comment: Are  you trying to convey this `((AbstractMessageChannel)outputChannel).addInterceptor(ctx.getBean("messageListener", ChannelInterceptor.class));` ?

Comment: Yes, the you will run out of memory; you should definitely not use an inteceptor this way. Yes, you can create a "service activator" on the fly - just implement `MessageHandler`, make the channel a `DirectChannel` and subscribe your handler to it. I suggest you read [the Spring Integration documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/) and take a look at [some of the samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples).

Comment: Thanks a lot!! MessageHandler saved my day .. :)